# Unable to connect with jmxmp in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jmx

In my spring + tomcat solution I have a problem, with jmxmp connection.

I have enabled jmx in tomcat + added jmxremote_optional.jar

This is manager.log

> INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache CollectionUsageThreshold
>
> javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CollectionUsage threshold is
>   not supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:13 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache
>   CollectionUsageThresholdCount javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CollectionUsage threshold is
>   not supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:13 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache
>   CollectionUsageThresholdExceeded
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CollectionUsage threshold is
>   not supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:13 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   Catalina:type=Resource,resourcetype=Global,class=org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase,name="UserDatabase"
>   modelerType javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: Cannot find
>   attribute modelerType
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:13 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Eden Space UsageThreshold
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Eden Space UsageThresholdCount
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Eden Space UsageThresholdExceeded
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Survivor Space UsageThreshold
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Survivor Space UsageThresholdCount
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Survivor Space
>   UsageThresholdExceeded javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Usage threshold is not
>   supported
>
> 05.09.2012 16:33:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache CollectionUsageThreshold
>   javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CollectionUsage threshold is
>   not supported
>   05.09.2012 16:33:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache
>   CollectionUsageThresholdCount javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CollectionUsage threshold is
>   not supported
>   05.09.2012 16:33:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: JMXProxy: Error getting attribute
>   java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code Cache Collecti

This is spring con.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">
    <bean id="test" class="test.Test" />
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    </bean> -->
    <bean id="serverConnector" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler"            >
                <property name="managedMethods">
                    <list>
                        <value>getVal</value>
                        <value>setVal</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="bean:name=Test" value-ref="test"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is java bean

```
public class Test {
    private String val = "";
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public void setVal(String v) {
        val = v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will response to my own question :).

Problem was, port 9875 (default port of jmxmp) was used by another service. 
Hope it helps anybody else and save his time